# Can't exec /usr/local/bin/node through PHP

Tags: linux, node.js

I am trying to launch a node.js server with a PHP file:

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/node /home/.../server.js >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

But it doesn't work... If I enter the command in terminal it does work though.

Is it because it is installed in usr/local/bin and I don't have the permission ?

Thank you

EDit: I found out that the node is running with
`ps -e|grep node` 
but the server is not working

Comment: It's asking password as you ran `sudo`.

Comment: Why do you need `sudo` anyway? If it's just for listening on port(s) < 1024, you could have iptables or other firewall route the lower port to a higher port (> 1024) that you can listen on without root.

Comment: without sudo it doesnt work either

Comment: "doesnt work" doesn't really tell/help us much.